Sort rows in a table in the given range
I'm trying to sort a table after removing an entry.
Function last_row(sheet_name,col_to_check)
    If sheet_name = "wl" Then
        Set ws = Sheets("Membership Waiting List")
        table_name = "waiting_list"
    ElseIf 'this part is for other sheet names so will omit.
    End If

    last_row = ws.ListObjects(table_name).Range.Columns(col_to_check).Cells.Find("*", 
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Function


Sub remove_and_refund()
    Dim wl As Worksheet
    Set wl = Sheets("Membership Waiting List")

    w_last_row = last_row("wl",1) ' confirmed this gives the expected value

    ' code to remove entry is omitted but would be here

    wl.Range("A3", "L" & w_last_row).Sort Key1:=wl.Range("A3", "A" & w_last_row), 
    Order1:=xlAscending 
    ' confirmed that the two ranges are correct by using .Select 
End Sub

The problem is that the sub includes the table headers in A2:L2 in the sorting.
I've used this method for tables in other sheets and haven't encountered this problem, so I assume it's not to do with the range being a table.

If you're going to use that Sort method rather than the table's Sort object, you should specify the Header:=xlNo argument.

I see, I didn't fully comprehend the table sort method honestly so I stuck with what I already knew. I've added the header argument and it's still sorting the header range. I'll do some work on table sorting and see if I can figure that out instead. Thanks

No need to find the last row, just use the ListColumns name or position.
In the first procedure I've used the column position .ListColumns(1), in the second I've used the name .ListColumns("H4").
Public Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Membership Waiting List").ListObjects("waiting_list")
        .Range.Sort _
            Key1:=.ListColumns(1), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, _
            OrderCustom:=1, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End With

End Sub  

Or this method which will add the sorted indicator (not sure of the technical name) to the filter button:
Public Sub Test1()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Membership Waiting List").ListObjects("waiting_list")
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
            Key:=.ListColumns("H4").Range, _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
            
        .Sort.Header = xlYes
        .Sort.MatchCase = False
        .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Sort.Apply
    End With
End Sub  

Edit:  Second procedure uses Add2, but just Add will work.

SortFields.Add2 method
Creates a new sort field and returns a SortFields object that can
optionally sort data types with the SubField defined.


I don't know what was causing the issue but I've found a workaround using table sort methods. The last line of the code above has been replaced with:
With wl.ListObjects("waiting_list").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3", "A" & w_last_row), Order:=xlAscending
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

